# Entity Framework 4 with POCO entities in different assemblies with associations that span assemblies

Tags: .net-3.5, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4

Is it possible to have such a scenario?

Entity Framework 4 POCO entities in different assemblies with associations between them (that span multiple assemblies) ?

Comment: I know this answer for EF1: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/5c624a85-86ff-44db-91a1-f043095292cf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see it now, without making something that loads entities from the other assemblies in that unit of work, the scenario is not possible.